# Sequence contains no elements Linq-to-Sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm having very strange problem in this simple linq query

```
return (from doc in db.umDocumentActions
                    where doc.sysDocument.ModuleID == modid
                    join roleaction in db.umRoleActions on doc.DocumentActionID equals roleaction.DocumentActionID
                    where roleaction.RoleID == roleID
                    select new { doc.DocumentID, roleaction.RoleID }).Count() > 0;
```

When this query is called it gives invalid operation exception telling me that sequence contains no elements. It happens when there is fair amount of traffic on the site. I am using following static method to get instance of datacontext.

```
public static EvoletDataContext Get() 
        {
            var connection = ProfiledDbConnection.Get(new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnstring"].ToString()));

            return new EvoletDataContext(connection);
            //return DataContextUtils.CreateDataContext<EvoletDataContext>(connection);
        }
```

I'm afraid that this method is creating problem as static methods are not thread safe. Any views?

Comment: The only threading issues I've had with contexts in the past have resulted in an exception complaing the DbReader is already in use/incorrect state/gone for coffee.  The error you're getting seems to indicate that there are no matching records.  Why do you need the anonymous type?  Remove that part and just use `Count()`?

Comment: In fact, you don't even need the count.  Use `.Any()`

Comment: @sumudge in fact code belongs to old days. now that its creating problems i will definitely consider changing it

Comment: If @DoctaJonez's answer doesn't resolve the issue, removing the anonymous type might.  Doing so will (should) ensure the `Count` or `Any` method is passed through the IQueryable magic and performed on the database as opposed to trying to count a potentially empty list.  (I assume it does actually give you a `new List<T>` when there are no results as opposed to `List<T>` - otherwise you'd get an ObjectNullReference, right?  Or does the QueryProvider get things confused?)

Comment: You shouldn't get an InvalidOperation exception from Counting an empty sequence, it should always return zero, so I suspect the issue is elsewhere.  "Sequence contains no elements" usually only occurs when you use `First` or `Single` on an empty sequence, so it's most likely being caused by a related property being accessed when there is no related data.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be that `sysDocument` is actually a seperate table with a reference to `DocumentID`.  This would normally mean that there would be a related collection of sysDocuments in the document class, but I'm guessing that you've changed the cardinality to `"one to one"` in the Linq to SQL designer.

When using a `"one to one"` cardinality, Linq to SQL uses the `Single()` method behind the scenes to get the `sysDocument`.  This means that if there are no related sysDocuments you will get an invalidoperation exception.

You can fix this by wither changing the cardinality in you Linq model from `"one to one"` to `"one to many"` and use the `SingleOrDefault()` method to get the related `sysDocument` from the sysDocuments collection.

If that doesn't sound appealing you can look in the database to find which document doesn't have a related `sysDocument` and fix it manually.

**UPDATE:**

Instead of basing the query off the documentActions, try basing it off the sysDocument table instead.  I've had to guess at what the table will be called so this might not compile, but hopefully you get the idea:

```
var query = from sysDocument in db.sysDocuments
            where sysDocument.ModuleID == modid
            let doc = sysDocument.umDocumentAction
            join roleaction in db.umRoleActions on doc.DocumentActionID equals roleaction.DocumentActionID
            where roleaction.RoleID == roleID
            select new { doc.DocumentID, roleaction.RoleID };

//return true if there are any results (this is more efficient than Count() > 0)
return query.Any();
```

Comment: that sounds like a lot of imagination :) let me check the designer and i will be back

Comment: @DoctaJones i have inspected the dbml and found out that relation in one-to-many like `sysDocument->umDocumentActions` so each umDocumentAction will have exactly one sysdocument object associated with it. could not find what's the root of the problem

Comment: @Muhammad Adeel Zahid please take a look at the code in my updated answer and see if that does the trick.